# Why can a no_std crate depend on a crate that uses std?

Tags: rust, rust-no-std

In the example, hs reexport HashSet from std. But it compiles without error or warning. Why?

```
#![no_std]

pub use hs::HashSet;

pub fn new() -> HashSet<usize> {
    HashSet::new()
}

pub fn insert(a: &mut HashSet<usize>, v: usize) {
    a.insert(v);
}
```

Comment: Does it run and work without any error/warning?

Comment: @Samathingamajig Yeah, you can try it at https://github.com/zxch3n/no_std_test

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well `#![no_std]` just means that you don't include `std` *by default*. It doesn't mean you can't explicitly or implicitly (i.e. through other crates) still include `std`. In other words `#![no_std]` does not prohibit using `std` but it disables using it by default.

For example this works, too:

```rust
#![no_std]
extern crate std;
fn main() {
    std::println!("hello!");
}
```

Comment: Could you give an example of including `std` explicitly with `#![no_std]`? So `#![no_std]` is more of a helper than a rigid rule, right?

Answer (score 1):

Every crate in Rust is opt-in, that is, you need to explicitly ask it as a dependency to have it as a dependency of your code (usually through `Cargo.toml`). All, but one: the standard library (hence the name), which is opt-out. That is to say, if you do nothing, Rust will implicitly understand you require it as a dependency, and you explicitly need to tell it that you don't (with `#![no_std]`) to prevent this. Besides this, `std` behaves like any other crate, that is, even if it's not one of your direct dependencies, you can still access to reexports of your actual dependencies.

It should be noted, however, that there is no reason to not want to standard library as a dependency except in situations where you just don't have it (for instance, if you are writing embedded code, or a kernel, or ...). In this case, having `std` as a (transitive) dependency will just fail at compile time, which means that not only you *have* to use `#[no_std]`, but so should all the dependencies you have, and their dependencies, and so on... In your case, you have annotated your code with `#[no_std]`, but there was no hard requirement for you to do so, so there is no problem in having a dependency that has access to `std`.

Finally, note that some parts of the standard library are accessible even if the whole standard library is not. For instance, `core` is not OS-dependent, so you can use it even on embedded, and usually obtaining `alloc` one way or another (that is, implementing what is required yourself for instance) also provides you quite a lot of the standard library. In particular, I think `HashSet` only requires `core` and `alloc` to be available, not the whole standard library.